# php mysql comparing dates for equality

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php to access fields from 2 tables.

This part works just fine

```
   $sql=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM user_weeks WHERE user_id = '.$_SESSION["user_id"].' ORDER BY date DESC') or die(mysql_error());
```

I get the date just fine by doing this

```
    $infodate=$info["date"];
    echo $infodate;
```

However I'm trying to take that date and compare it to one in a different table as such

```
$sql2=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM weekly_ROI WHERE date = '.$infodate.' ') or die(mysql_error());
```

however, that gives me no results. I'm a noob so sorry if this code is so "2000 and late"

Comment: What type is the column `date`?

Comment: date  is reserved word use to wrap inside the backtick ```date```

Comment: both are listed in the database as "date" as the type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you're using a standard `yyyy-mm-dd` type date string in your query, which means you're lacking quotes around the date value:

```
$sql2=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM weekly_ROI WHERE date = '.$infodate.' ')
                                                         ^--here          ^-- here
```

Your query will look like

```
... WHERE date = 2013-12-18
```

and be evaluated as a simple mathematical subtraction:

```
... WHERE date = 1983
```

You need quotes:

```
.... date = "' . $infodate . '"');
            ^--               ^--
```

Comment: Thanks this is what ultimately solved the problem for me. Thanks go out to everyone though!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming both date fields are of type date, you need to wrap the name date in backticks, since date is a reserved word and you need to wrap your date in quotes.

```
$sql2=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM weekly_ROI WHERE `date` = "'.$infodate. '"') or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, mysql_* functions are deprecated.  You need to look into using PDO or mysqli to query your database.

Comment: I think `.. = 2013-12-20 12:33:01` won't work until you set `$infodate` in single quotes.

Comment: `date` is actually NOT a reserved word. It should be, but it's exempted in mysql as a special case: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html  - see section 9.3

Answer (score 2):

**date** is reserved word use to wrap inside the backtick `date

```
$sql2=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM weekly_ROI WHERE `date` = "'.$infodate.'" ') or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It is NOT a reserved word. See section 9.3: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html